# Is there a way to use "parents" instanced methods in a "child" instance and iterate over multiple "parent" instances in a "child" instance?

Tags: python, class

Let's assume we have a class `Person` and a class `Group`

After I created instances of `Person` I add those to an instance of `Group`.
Now I want to use the same class methods from `Person` on a `Group` instance.

Is that possible with inheritance and those "Dunder Methods", `__getitem__()`, `__iter__()`, `__next__()` ?

```
class Group(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.persons = []

    def add_person(self, person):
        self.persons.append(person)
    
    '''
    What do I need to add to also use `Person` class methods and those 
    methods iterate over the list `self.persons`
    '''

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, status):
        self.name = name
        self.status= status

    def print_info(self):
        print(f'This is {self.name} with the status: {self.status}\n.')

    def update_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def update_status(self, status):
        self.status = status

p1 = Person("John", 0)
p2 = Person("Dave", 0)
p3 = Person("Susan", 0)

group = Group()
group.add_person(p1)
group.add_person(p2)
group.add_person(p3)

group.print_info()
#expected result:
#This is John with the status: 0.
#This is Dave with the status: 0.
#This is Susan with the status: 0.

group.update_status(1)

group.print_info()
#expected result:
#This is John with the status: 1.
#This is Dave with the status: 1.
#This is Susan with the status: 1.
```

Comment: dunder = double under. Why do you call the property "name" if it's supposed to be a list? Name is singular, a list is plural.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you have a list and you want to iterate over it, you use a loop. What do you mean by *"automatically iterate"*? Why does a `Person` get a ***list*** of names? Please clarify

Comment: "Down-Under Methods", I love it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller because the minimum is one person.

Comment: @nap so, to clarify, a single `Person` object might represent several individuals? Or is it that the _class_ is supposed to keep a record of all the `Person` objects? It seems unusual that a class named `Person` would be a collection of people.

Comment: Specifically for `print`, you can use iterable unpacking: `print("this is", *["John", "Dave", "Susan"])` or `print("this is", *self.name)` will give `this is John Dave Susan`. But again, it is hard to say about the general case. Please elaborate

Comment: *"I want to use the same class methods from Person on a Group instance"* - that can only be done if `Group` inherits from `Person`, but that doesn't really sound logical... You just do `for person in self.persons: person.method()`...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since the list has been saved in the member `self.name`, you can use that to iterate over.

```
def print_name(self):
    for name in self.name:
        print(f'This is {name}.')
```

Comment: I find this kind repetitive if you imagine a class with 100 class methods.

Comment: @nap care to elaborate?

Comment: @nap: which class with 100 methods? You didn't tell about that. What do you want to do with those 100 methods? Call them all for as many times as items are in the list?